# Assign dynamic variables in __init__ python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to assign variables dynamically to a class:

Example:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, field):
       for key, value in self.func(field):
           self.key = value

field = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}

obj = P(field)
print(obj.a)
print(obj.b)
```

Here I want to assign attributes dynamically to a object, basically keys of field dict as attribute. but I think it will assign 'key' as attribute to that object. How can we do this?

Comment: What is `self.func`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setattr`, so that the *value* of the variable, not the name, is used as the attribute to set.

```
for key, value in self.func(field):
    setattr(self, value, key)
```

Not knowing what `self.func` is, it's possible you just want to use the dictionary to initialize attributes, in which case you want

```
for key, value in field.items():
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

or simply

```
self.__dict__.update(field)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setattr` to set attributes dynamically:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, field):
       for key, value in field.items():  # <== note "items" needed here
           setattr(self, key, value)

field = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}

obj = P(field)
print(obj.a)  # 1
print(obj.b)  # 2
```

Comment: You lost the call to `self.func` (whatever that is).

Comment: @chepner Yes, that was somewhat deliberate. From the description it appears that the items are contained directly in `field` and that `self.func` is what the OP thought might be necessary to extract them - in fact `field.items()`

Comment: @chepner BTW, my assumption was largely based on the fact that the key names were the same as in `field` itself. I now see that you've added a good answer allowing for both possible interpretations, so thanks for that.